# With play and akka-https: How to properly chain multiple requests to the incoming request to create a response?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

So I tried to get a small play app communicating with another rest service.
The idea is, to receive a request on the play side and then do a request to the rest api and feed parts of the result to another local actor before displaying the response from the local actor and the rest service in the browser.
[This image shows how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R55nm.png)

And I tried to do it with streams. I got it all working, but I am absolutely not happy with the part where I talk to my local actor and create a `Future[(Future[String],Future[String])` tuple , so I would be happy if you could point me in the direction, how to do this in an elegant and clean way.

So here is my code. The input is a csv file.
My local actor creates an additional graphic I want to put into the response.

```
def upload = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
 request.body.file("input").map { inputCsv =>

 //csv to list of strings
 val inputList: List[String] = convertFileToList(inputCsv)

 //http request to rest service
 val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = httpRequest(inputList, "/path",4321 ,"0.0.0.0")

 //pattern match response and ask local actor
 val formattedResult = responseFuture.flatMap { response =>
  response.status match {
    case akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes.OK =>
      val resultTeams = Unmarshal(response.entity).to[CustomResultCaseClass]

     //the part I'd like to improve
      val tupleFuture = resultTeams.map(result => 
        (Future(result.teams.reduce(_ + "," + _)),
          plotter.ask(PlotData(result.eval)).mapTo[ChartPath].flatMap(plotAnswer => Future(plotAnswer.path))))
      tupleFuture.map(tuple => tuple._1.map(teams => 
        p._2.map(chartPath => Ok(views.html.upload(teams))(chartPath))))).flatMap(a => a).flatMap(b => b)
   }
 }
 formattedResult
}.getOrElse(Future(play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045936/scalas-for-comprehension-with-futures) are useful for this type of use cases.  A basic example which demonstrates the refactoring involved:

```
val teamFut = Future(result.teams.reduce(_ + "," + _))

//I think the final .flatMap(Future(_.path)) is unnecessary it should be
// .map(_.path), but I wanted to replicate the question code functionality
val pathFut = plotter.ask(PlotData(result.eval))
                     .mapTo[ChartPath]
                     .flatMap(Future(_.path))

val okFut = 
  for {
    teams     <- teamFut
    chartPath <- pathFut      
  } yield Ok(views.html.upload(teams))(chartPath)
```

Note: the Initial Futures should be instantiated outside of the for otherwise parallel execution won't occur.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be exactly the right tool here. Do you in general think the way I implemented it is the a good way or would you approach it in another way?

Comment: @rincewind You are welcome.  In general your implementation seems fine.  Just be careful of overusing Futures, there is a significant initial cost at instantiation.  For example, `result.teams` would have to be pretty big to warrant a Future for just a `reduce`.  Happy hacking.