# How to use for instead of flatMap/map in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm in stack to understand how Scala `for` works.
I think codes below could be written with `for` though I don't have any idea how.
Could someone explain me how I can do that?

```
def foo: Future[Option[Int]] = ???
def bar: Future[Throwable Xor Option[Int]] = ???
def baz: Future[Option[Boolean]] = ???

foo.flatMap {
  case Some(x) =>
    Future.successful(x)
  case None =>
    bar.flatMap {
      case Xor.Right(Some(x)) =>
        baz.map {
          case true => 1
          case false => 0
        }
      case Xor.Right(None) =>
        Future.successful(0)
      case Xor.Left(_) =>
        Future.successful(-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045936/scalas-for-comprehension-with-futures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pattern match in for-comprehensions. See [Allow pattern matching on type in for comprehensions](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900).

Perhaps you can use [Monad Transformers](https://speakerdeck.com/eamelink/flatten-your-code). I do want to implement your code in that manner, but I don't have time for that now. Maybe the hint can help you.

*/Edit This is not completely correct as pointed out by the comment of Sergey. You can pattern match in for-comprehensions as long as all matches are of the same type. See this image taken from the [second lesson of the first week of Functional Program Design in Scala Coursera Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun2/lecture/apcY8/recap-collections) where all patterns inherit from `JSON`:*

[image: For-comprehension and pattern matching]

Comment: This is correct, with one addition: It actually _is_ possible to pattern match in a for-comprehension, however, you are able to provide only one case for the match, and it acts as a filter instead of throwing MatchError: `for { Some(x) <- List(Some(1), None, Some(2)) } yield x` would yield a `List(1, 2)`

Comment: That first presentation you linked is the most useful resource on understanding advanced Scala I've ever read.

Answer (score 4):

With all the branching inside the `flatMap` functions, it won't be possible to write this as a for comprehension.

It is possible to replace pattern matching with a `fold` method, but this may be a matter of personal preference.

```
Option("suish") match {
  case Some(name) => s"hello $name"
  case None => "hello world"
}
// is analogous to
Option("suish").fold("hello world")(name => s"hello $name")
```

I rewrote your pattern matching using the `fold` methods of [`OptionT`](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/index.html#cats.data.OptionT) ([tutorial](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/optiont.html)), [`XorT`](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/index.html#cats.data.XorT) and `Option`, but I'm not sure if this is more readable than your nested pattern matches.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.{Xor, XorT, OptionT}

def foo: Future[Option[Int]] = none[Int].pure[Future]
def bar: Future[Throwable Xor Option[Int]] = 2.some.right.pure[Future]
def baz: Future[Option[Boolean]] = true.some.pure[Future]

OptionT(foo).getOrElseF {
  // foo : case None
  XorT(bar).fold(
    // bar : case Xor.Left
    _ => -1.pure[Future],
    barO => barO.fold(
      // bar : case Xor.Right(None)
      0.pure[Future])(
      // bar : case Xor.Right(Some(x))
      _ => baz.map(_.fold(0 /* ? */)(b => if (b) 1 else 0)))
  ).flatten
}
// Future[Int]
```

Comment: thanks for answering. like you mentioned in the answer,nested pattern matches are more readable to me. I guess Monad transformer is the way to go

Comment: @suish `OptionT` and `XorT` are monad transformers.

Comment: my bad. I was trying to say `for` using Monad transformer is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but I just showed in my answer that you cannot use monad tranformers to write a for comprehension in this case.