# Waiting for another future to end to return a function

Tags: scala, future

Let's say I have a function `func1` that needs to return a `Future` with two integers. Each of the two values are returned by independent futures, like so:

```
def f1 = Future { 1 }
def f2 = Future { 2 }

def func1 : Future[(Int,Int)] = {

    val future1 = f1
    future1.map { result1 =>
       result1 * 10
    }

    val future2 = f2
    future2.map { result2 =>
       result2 * 20
    }

}
```

I need `future1` wait until `future2` ends (or vice versa) to return both results as `(Int,Int)`. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's precisely what the `zip` method on futures does:

```
val futurePair: Future[(Int, Int)] = future1.zip(future2)
```

Note that if you haven't instantiated your futures before (say, if `future1` and `future2` are `def`s, not `val`s), this will run the two computations in parallel, while a for comprehension (or `flatMap`) would wait for the first one to succeed before starting the second one.

Comment: What happens if there are 3 or 4 futures?  Is it possible to have a Tuple4?  Or will it be nested tuples?

Comment: It will be nested tuples. But you can always use `map` to give them the form you desire. If you have a `List[Future[Int]]`, you can even use the static method `Future.sequence` to wait for all of them into a `Future[List[Int]]`.

Comment: To explain what I mean about using `map`, you can do `future1 zip future2 zip future3 map { case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c) }`

Answer (score 1):

A `for`-comprehension is the best option here:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def f1 = Future{1}
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> def f2 = Future{2}
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> for {result1 <- f1; result2 <- f2} yield (result1 * 10, result2 * 20)
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[(Int, Int)] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@71f67a79
```

More information can be found [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-use-multiple-scala-futures-in-for-comprehension-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046133/2661491).

**Note:** this will run the two `Future`s in sequence while [Cyrille Corpet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791493/2661491) will run them in parallel.

Comment: This runs the f1 and f2 in sequence. The other answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-comprehension for futures that have already started like this:

```
val f1: Future[Int] = ???
val f2: Future[Int] = ???
val f3: Future[Int] = ???

val futureInts: Future[(Int, Int, Int)] = for {
  result1 <- f1
  result2 <- f2
  result3 <- f3
} yield (result1, result2, result3)
```

If the futures were assigned to `lazy val`s or `defs` then this wouldn't work, because the futures would not have been started (if you start the futures inside the for comprehension, then they will be executed sequentially).  Here is an example of starting them, and then waiting for them with `for`.

Example:

```
val f1: Future[Int] = Future {
  println("starting f1")
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  1
}
val f2: Future[Int] = Future {
  println("starting f2")
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  2
}
val f3: Future[Int] = Future {
  println("starting f3")
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  3
}

val futureInts: Future[(Int, Int, Int)] = for {
  result1 <- f1
  result2 <- f2
  result3 <- f3
} yield (result1, result2, result3)

futureInts.map {
  case tuple => println(tuple)
}
```

Output:

```
starting f1 // These first 
starting f3 // threes statements
starting f2 // happen right away.

(1,2,2)     // Then this prints a three seconds later
```

In your case you could do this:

```
def func1 : Future[(Int,Int)] = {

  // Start futures
  val future1 = f1.map(_ * 10)
  val future2 = f2.map(_ * 20)

  // Wait for both futures, and return a tuple
  for {
    result1 <- future1
    result2 <- future2
  } yield (result1, result2)

}
```