# Return Future[(Int,Int)] instead of (Future[Int],Future[Int])

Tags: scala

I have the following futures:

```
def f1 = Future {1}    
def f2 = Future {2}
```

I need the following code to return `Future[(Int,Int)]` :

```
val future = // function that returns a future
future.flatMap {
    val x1 = f1
    val x2 = f2
    (x1,x2)  // This returns Future[Int],Future[Int] 
}
```

Instead of `(Future[Int],Future[Int])` I need the function to return `Future[(Int,Int)]`. How to convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for another future to end to return a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790952/waiting-for-another-future-to-end-to-return-a-function)

Comment: I think you have accepted the wrong answer here - see mine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take issue with the (currently) accepted answer here. As per my  comment, this is not really the *correct* way to **zip** together two futures. the correct way is simply this:

```
f1 zip f2
```

The other answer:

```
for (x <- f1; y <- f2) yield (x, y)
```

Whilst this will work, it is not parallel in the case that `f2` is an expression yielding a future (as it is in this question). If this is the case, `f2` will not be constructed until the first future has completed **[1]**. Whilst `zip` has been implemented in terms of `flatMap` in the same way, because its argument is strict, the second future is already running (subject to the execution context of course).

It's also more succinct!

**[1]** - this can be seen by observing that `y`, the value computed by `f1`, is in scope as `f2` is constructed

#### Appendix

This can be demonstrated easily:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._; import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def createAndStartFuture(i: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
     |   println(s"starting $i in ${Thread.currentThread.getName} at ${java.time.Instant.now()}")
     |   Thread.sleep(20000L)
     |   i
     | }
createAndStartFuture: (i: Int)scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
```

With this:

```
scala> for (x <- createAndStartFuture(1); y <- createAndStartFuture(2)) yield (x, y)
starting 1 in scala-execution-context-global-34 at 2017-05-05T10:29:47.635Z
res15: scala.concurrent.Future[(Int, Int)] = Future(<not completed>)

// Waits 20s
starting 2 in scala-execution-context-global-32 at 2017-05-05T10:30:07.636Z
```

But with zip

```
scala> createAndStartFuture(1) zip createAndStartFuture(2)
starting 1 in scala-execution-context-global-34 at 2017-05-05T10:30:45.434Z
starting 2 in scala-execution-context-global-32 at 2017-05-05T10:30:45.434Z
res16: scala.concurrent.Future[(Int, Int)] = Future(<not completed>)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic use case for a for comprehension.

```
for {
    x1 <- f1
    x2 <- f2
} yield (x1, x2)
```

This is equivalent to a flatmap followed by a map

```
f1.flatMap(x1 => f2.map(x2 => (x1,x2)))
```

Since you will not reach the inside of f1.flatMap until x1 is ready, this code will execute sequentially.

If you wish for the futures to execute concurrently, you can instantiated the futures before the for comprehension.

```
val future1 = f1
val future2 = f2
for {
    x1 <- future1
    x2 <- future2
} yield (x1, x2)
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this solution is sub-optimal because it will not start `f2` until `f1` has completed :-(

Comment: @oxbow_lakes It is easy to choose the execution strategy with a for comprehension. You can simply instantiate the futures before the for comprehension to achieve concurrency. The question never mentioned that it wanted the futures to execute concurrently.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes in many cases, sequential processing is the desired result.

Comment: It's a sub-optimal solution; it's way more code, it reinvents the wheel and if you wanted sequential computation, you wouldn't be using futures

Comment: @oxbow_lakes It is identical in performance, uses built in language constructs, and is more flexible as it scales to any number of futures easily. Many times I have needed to perform an async operation, then depending on its result, perform another async operation.