# Scala Future for comprehension: sequential vs parallel

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing, future

Here we have `SeqPar` object which contains a `task` routine which is a simple mock `Future` which prints out some debugging info and returns `Future[Int]` type.

The question is: why `experiment1` is allowed to run in parallel, while `experiment2` always runs sequentially?

```
object SeqPar {
  def experiment1: Int = {
    val f1 = task(1)
    val f2 = task(2)
    val f3 = task(3)

    val computation = for {
      r1 <- f1
      r2 <- f2
      r3 <- f3
    } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

    Await.result(computation, Duration.Inf)
  }

  def experiment2: Int = {
    val computation = for {
      r1 <- task(1)
      r2 <- task(2)
      r3 <- task(3)
    } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

    Await.result(computation, Duration.Inf)
  }

  def task(i: Int): Future[Int] = {
    Future {
      println(s"task=$i thread=${Thread.currentThread().getId} time=${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
      i * i
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `experiment1` it prints out:

```
task=3 thread=24 time=1541326607613
task=1 thread=22 time=1541326607613
task=2 thread=21 time=1541326607613
```

While `experiment2`:

```
task=1 thread=21 time=1541326610653
task=2 thread=20 time=1541326610653
task=3 thread=21 time=1541326610654
```

What is the reason for the observed difference? I do know that `for` comprehension desugared like `f1.flatMap(r1 => f2.flatMap(r2 => f3.map(r3 => r1 + r2 + r3)))` but I still missing a point why one is allowed to run in parallel and another isn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala's "for comprehension" with futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045936/scalas-for-comprehension-with-futures)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an effect of what `Future(…)` and `flatMap` do:

- `val future = Future(task)` starts running task in parallel
- `future.flatMap(result => task)` arranges for running `task` when `future` completes

Note that `future.flatMap(result => task)` cannot start running task in parallel before `future` completes because to run `task`, we need `result`, which is only available when `future` completes.

Now lets look at your `example1`:

```
def experiment1: Int = {
  // construct three independent tasks and start running them
  val f1 = task(1)
  val f2 = task(2)
  val f3 = task(3)

  // construct one complicated task that is ...
  val computation =
    // ... waiting for f1 and then ...
    f1.flatMap(r1 =>
      // ... waiting for f2 and then ...
      f2.flatMap(r2 =>
        // ... waiting for f3 and then ...
        f3.map(r3 =>
          // ... adding some numbers.
          r1 + r2 + r3)))

  // now actually trigger all the waiting
  Await.result(computation, Duration.Inf)
}
```

So in `example1`, since all three tasks take the same time and were started at the same time, we probably only have to block when waiting for `f1`. When we get around to wait for the `f2`, its result should already been there.

Now how does `example2` differ?

```
def experiment2: Int = {
  // construct one complicated task that is ...
  val computation =
    // ... starting task1 and then waiting for it and then ...
    task(1).flatMap(r1 =>
      // ... starting task2 and then waiting for it and then ...
      task(2).flatMap(r2 =>
        // ... starting task3 and then waiting for it and then ...
        task(3).map(r3 =>
          // ... adding some numbers.
          r1 + r2 + r3)))

  // now actually trigger all the waiting and the starting of tasks
  Await.result(computation, Duration.Inf)
}
```

In this example, we are not even constructing `task(2)` before we have waited for `task(1)` to finish, so the tasks cannot run in parallel.

So when programming with Scala's `Future`, you have to control your concurrency by choosing correctly between code like `example1` and code like `example2`. Or you can look into libraries that provide more explicit control over concurrency.

Comment: Thank you @Toxaris , such a quality answer, everything is clear now!

Answer (score 1):

This is because Scala Futures are strict. The operation inside a Future is executed as soon as the Future is created and then it memoizes its value. So you are losing referential transparency. In your case your futures are executed  in your first **task** call, the result is memoized. They are not executed again inside the for. In the second case futures are created in your for comprehension and the result is correct.