# Running scala Futures conncurrently in for comprehension without future variables in local scope

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Suppose I have a future result, let's call it `garfield`

```scala
def garfield = Future{
  Thread.sleep(100)
  System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

I can run `garfield` concurrently with in `for comprehension` like this

```scala
val f1 = garfield
val f2 = garfield

for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
} yield r1 -> r2
```

as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046133/1507124) answer.

Suppose I don't want to polluting the local scope with future variables if I won't need them later. Is this a valid alternative approach?

```scala
for {
  f1 <- Future{garfield}
  f2 <- Future{garfield}
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
} yield r1 -> r2
```

## Edit

It appears my original approach, using `Future.apply` includes overhead that most of the time causes sequential execution, see [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xKtHUMEVRDabuIfLUs3WBA).

Using the alternative approach

```scala
for {
  f1 <- Future.successful(garfield)
  f2 <- Future.successful(garfield)
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
} yield r1 -> r2
```

behaves as expected.

Then again, this approach is a bit odd and perhaps a more conventional approach of scoping the futures in a `Unit` is preferred.

```scala
val res = {
  val f1 = garfield
  val f2 = garfield
  for {
    r1 <- f1
    r2 <- f2
  } yield r1 -> r2
}
```

I'm curios if someone could shed some more light on the reason for the sporadic lack of concurrent execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comprehension is sequential in principal, so no, this won't work.

Your code will sequentially evaluate f1 and then f2.

The following should work

(Updated with some changes from [link](https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-2.html) from @ViktorKlang )

```scala
object FutureFor extends App {
  import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  for {
    _ <- Future.unit
    f1 = Future { "garfield" }
    f2 = Future { "garfield" }
    r1 <- f1
    r2 <- f2
  } yield r1 -> r2

}
```

You have to start with `<-` to consume from "initial" future and it will decide the outcome type of for-comprehension.

The concurrency would be achieved with `=` as it will create Futures and then consume them with `<-`

But this is really confusing and I'd suggest to stick to

```scala
val f1 = garfield
val f2 = garfield

for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
} yield r1 -> r2
```

Edit:

Your approach `Future { garfield() }` does work and I missed the point that it is wrapping a Future.

And it is concurrent. See modified code that proves it:

```scala
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.Random

object FutureFor extends App {
  private val random = new Random()
  implicit val ex =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  def garfield() = Future {
    val started = Instant.now()
    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000))
    val stopped = Instant.now()
    s"Started:$started on ${Thread.currentThread().getName}. Stopped $stopped"
  }

  val bar = Future
    .sequence {
      for {
        _ <- 1 to 10
      } yield
        for {
          f1 <- Future { garfield() }
          f2 <- Future { garfield() }
          r1 <- f1
          r2 <- f2
        } yield r1 + "\n" + r2
    }
    .map(_.mkString("\n\n"))
    .foreach(println)

  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Prints:

```
Started:2020-04-24T13:23:46.043230Z on pool-1-thread-3. Stopped 2020-04-24T13:23:46.889296Z
Started:2020-04-24T13:23:46.428162Z on pool-1-thread-10. Stopped 2020-04-24T13:23:47.159586Z
....
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan. I'm really confused though because every so often it apears to execute concurrently https://scastie.scala-lang.org/U5Q1OWzRTNyL3s8bfXUnIA. You might have to repeat the run a few times.

Comment: Hmmm... something strange is going on when I experiment with this. Maybe it's related to the overhead of calling `Future.apply`

Comment: I've done some more experimenting https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XTMxslICRfKlQexADWCGcA and I'm puzzled by the results. Perhaps someone could share light on why alternative approach is sometimes sequential and sometimes concurrent

Comment: My guess is that the overhead of `Future.apply` sometimes causes my alternative to execute sequentially. When I change to `Future.successful(garfield)`, execution is as expected. It also appears it might be faster than the standard way https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xKtHUMEVRDabuIfLUs3WBA

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc @CervEd It's important to distinguish "eligibility for concurrency" and "concurrent execution". Ivan's code above makes both `f1` and `f2` *eligible* for concurrent execution—how they are actually executed and in which order is completely up to the discretion of the `ExecutionContext` and ultimately to the OS Thread Scheduler.

Comment: @ViktorKlang, that's a fair point. My understanding is that all the approaches in my example would be eligible for concurrent execution with no guarantee in the order of execution of `f1` and `f2`, regardless of whether they are within the same iteration. Any sequential execution is inadvertent. Although wrapping `Futures` within a `Future.apply`, as I originally did, instead of in a `Future.successful` seems redundant.

Comment: @CervEd The approach I recommend is the following: https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-2.html

Comment: @ViktorKlang, I'm still a bit puzzled why it executes rather differently than the regular "assigning to `val` approach", the only difference being a blocking map call on a successful future. Then again, all things being concurrent I suppose it doesn't really matter

Comment: @CervEd The difference is that `Future { Future {} }` doesn't do anything else but become Future[Future[_]] which happens almost instantaneously (it does not mean that the embedded Future has even started to execute yet)

Comment: @ViktorKlang, no I mean the approach both you and Ivan suggested, it executes rather differently than `val f1f = f1()` `for { f1 <- f1f ...`, which given that they desugar to almost the same thing puzzles me

Comment: @CervEd Future.unit is already completed, and then the val-assignments are evaluated.

Comment: @ViktorKlang @CervEd Thanks for comments. I updated the answer with `unit` instead of `successful`

Comment: @ViktorKlang, yeah no exactly. I think I'm just getting confused by the apparent pattern in the Scastie runtime system

Comment: @ViktorKlang, the method you proposed, that should still work even if there was just one future, right? Ie `_ <- Future.unit; fv = Future{...}; v <- fv`. I know it doesn't make sense, but I just into an issue where things stopped working because I remove a future and I just want to make sure that's not expected behavior

Comment: Yeah—it doesn't matter. But remember eligibility for concurrency does not mean guaranteed concurrency—that's up to the EC to decide.